# I am getting error on highcharts. like "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined"

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts

I am getting this error on the HighCharts chart like this error below:

The image of Error is:
[image: This is the image of the Error]

this is my angular app where I am getting this kind of error.
the component.ts file code is below:

```
  highchartspie = Highcharts;
  StatuschartOptions:{};
  HomeDashboardData;
  TodayDueandOverDue;
  MyBugsList;

  displayedColumns = ['assignee', 'bugtitle', 'icon', 'date'];
  constructor(private http:HttpClient,
    private route:ActivatedRoute,
    private Spinner:NgxSpinnerService,
    private dialog:MatDialog) {}


  ngOnInit(){
    this.Spinner.show();
    this.http.get(this.baseURI+'Projects/HomeDashboard?userid='+this.userid+'').subscribe(
      (data:any) => {
        //console.log(data);
        this.HomeDashboardData=data;
        this.TodayDueandOverDue=data.allOverDuebugs;
        this.MyBugsList = data.myOpenbugsList;
        this.StatuschartOptions = {
          chart : {
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
          },
          legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            labelFormatter: function () {
                return this.name + ' - ' + this.y;
            }
          },
          title : {
            text: null
          },
          tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return '<div>Status : ' + this.point.name + '</div><div style="text-align:center;">Count : ' + this.point.y + '</div>';
            }
          },
          plotOptions : {
            pie: {
              allowPointSelect: true,
              cursor: 'pointer',
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
              },
              showInLegend: true
            }
          },
          credits:{
            enabled: false
          },
          series : [{
              type: 'pie',
              data: [{
                name: 'Fixed',
                y: parseInt(this.HomeDashboardData.allProjectBugStatusChart.split('::')[0])
            }, {
                name: 'Open',
                y: parseInt(this.HomeDashboardData.allProjectBugStatusChart.split('::')[1]),
                color: '#32AE47'
            }, {
                name: 'Close',
                y: parseInt(this.HomeDashboardData.allProjectBugStatusChart.split('::')[2]),
                color: '#F44336'
            }, {
                name: 'Pending',
                y: parseInt(this.HomeDashboardData.allProjectBugStatusChart.split('::')[3])
            }, {
                name: 'Reject',
                y: parseInt(this.HomeDashboardData.allProjectBugStatusChart.split('::')[4])
            }, {
                name: 'Irreproducible',
                y: parseInt(this.HomeDashboardData.allProjectBugStatusChart.split('::')[5]),
                color: 'rgb(67, 67, 72)'
            }]
          }]
        };
    )
  }
```

And my component.html file is like below:

```
  <div>
    <highcharts-chart
      [Highcharts] = "highchartspie"
      [options] = "StatuschartOptions"
      style = "width:100%;height: 270px;display: block;">
    </highcharts-chart>
  </div>
```

So if anyone can help me with this question come up with your best solutions for this problem. every solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StatuschartOptions` is not defined yet when the `highcharts-chart` component is initialised. That's because you are using a http call to get your data. One way to fix it is by adding an `*ngIf`:

```
  <div>
    <highcharts-chart *ngIf="StatuschartOptions"
      [Highcharts] = "highchartspie"
      [options] = "StatuschartOptions"
      style = "width:100%;height: 270px;display: block;">
    </highcharts-chart>
  </div>
```